# how to point to a Button position based on tag value on horizontal UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

Hi fiends I'm new to ios app dev. I've struck with simple issue that in my app I added UIScrollView that scrolls horizontally. I've added buttons to that scrollview that will be dynamically changes. the code is

```
Step 1:

scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc]init];
    scroll.delegate=self;
    scroll.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, (height+25));
    [scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake((width-30)*n, height+25)];
    scroll.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    scroll.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"GP-BG.png"]];
    scroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator=NO;
    scroll.alwaysBounceHorizontal=NO;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        MODELRoom *room = [self.resultSet.dataObjectList objectAtIndex:i];
        CGRect rectForTitleButton = CGRectMake(i*(width-30), 0, width-30, height+25);
        int buttonTag =10000+i;
        UIButton *titleButton = [self getRoomButton:room tag:buttonTag];
        titleButton.tag=buttonTag;
        [titleButton setFrame:rectForTitleButton];

        titleButton.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        [scroll addSubview:titleButton];
        [controlButtons addObject:titleButton];
}
}

step 2:

- (UIButton*)getRoomButton:(MODELRoom *)currenRoom tag:(int)tagValue{
    UIButton *button=[[UIButton alloc] init];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIImage *buttonImageNormal;
    if(currenRoom.currentlySelected){
        buttonImageNormal=[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"GP-BG-Slected Green.png"]];
    }else{
        buttonImageNormal=[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""]];
    }
    [button setBackgroundImage:buttonImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [gridViewObjects addObject:button];
    return button;
}

step 3:

- (void)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender{
    if((int)[sender tag]>=10000 && (int)[sender tag]<20000){
        currentRoom=((MODELRoom*)[resultSet.dataObjectList objectAtIndex:[sender tag]-10000]);
        [self roomSelectionChanged:currentRoom];
        currentRoom.currentlySelected=true;
        scrollStrech=(width-30)*([sender tag]-10000);
        scroll.contentOffset=CGPointMake(scrollStrech, 0);
        NSLog(@"Scroll Strech=%d",scrollStrech);
        for(int i=0;i<[resultSet.dataObjectList count];i++){
            if(![[resultSet.dataObjectList objectAtIndex:i] isEqual:currentRoom]){
                ((MODELRoom*)[resultSet.dataObjectList objectAtIndex:i]).currentlySelected=false;
            }
        }
        [self refresh];
}

step 4:

-(void)refresh{
if([self.scroll isDescendantOfView:self.view]){
    [self.scroll removeFromSuperview];
}

}
```

Every thing is working fine but when I select the fifth or sixth button that is visible after scrolling and if I select that button the scroll view is rebouncing to first position. I found that this is coz of removing from superview and loading it again. if that the case also I need to show the scrollview region at that selected button region only.

kindly suggest me how to overcome this....

Comment: try to use `scroll.contentOffset=CGPointMake(sender.frame.origin.x, 0);` in button action

Comment: tried but it moves directly to that position which means the selected region will becoming first button by disappearing previous buttons... can you suggest me by making use of button tags.... as we have currently selected button....?

Comment: i am not understand exactly what you want.. can u explain bit more???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this on buttonClicked

```
    CGRect rect= CGRectMake(sender.frame.origin.x, sender.frame.origin.y , sender.frame.size.width, sender.frame.size.height);
    [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:rect animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks...But when i select next button the previous button is hiding till end of scroll view...

Comment: On step 2 you are not giving a background image when button is not currentlySelected.i guess..it may be because of that